# Reading and Writing Tables in Fortran

Tags: io, fortran

I have a calendar table with rise and set times in the form of

```
   Jan       Feb     ....    Dec
rise set  rise set   .... rise set
0643 1754 0433 1305  .... 1256 0219
1057 2230 1038 9999  .... 1502 0151
0912 9999 1026 0139  .... 1559 0103
1147 0149            .... 1739 0130
```

(Don't worry about the 9999's, I'll deal with them later. The blank space at the end of February indicates the day doesn't exist)

Obviously, instead of loading up the entire year in an array (which will be a nightmare when trying to figure out the DOY for any given set of times), I would like to handle the data two columns at a time.I tried writing the script with a variable in format like so:

```
26     format(<iskip>X,I2,3X,I2)
       idoy=001
       iskip=4
       irise1=00
4      read(1,26,end=6,err=4)irise2,iset2
       if (irise2.eq.iset2) go to 6    !if both blank, move to next column
7      irise1=irise2
       iset1=iset2
       irise2=99
       iset2=99
       idoy++
       go to 4

6      iskip=iskip+11
       irise1=irise2
       iset1=iset2
       irise2=99
       iset2=99
       idoy++
       if (iskip.lt.128) go to 4
```

Basically the program will read the columns two at a time, store the data and keep track of the day of the year.

To experiment with the idea of using a variable in format, I've created a test program that prints out a 10x24 matrix of values that should look like DOYHH column-by-column:

```
    integer idoy,ihour,iskip

    idoy=1
    ihour=0
    iskip=0

    do while (idoy.le.10)
            do while (ihour.lt.24)
 2                  format(<iskip>X,I3,I2)
                    write(2,2)idoy,ihour
            end do
            iskip=iskip+6
    end do
    end
```

But the compilers for both f77 and f95 seemed really unhappy with this. Any suggestions on how to get the test program working? I can probably extrapolate the technique from there. Again, it's really important that the test program writes to the bottom of the matrix and then restarts at the top.

Error Message from F77:

```
test.f: In program `MAIN__':
test.f:9:
    2                  format(<iskip>X,I3,I2)
                                     ^
Variable-expression FORMAT specifier at (^) -- unsupported
```

Error Message from F95:

```
test.f:9.16:
 2  format(<iskip>X,I3,I2)
           1
Error: Unexpected element '<' in format string at (1)
test.f:10.17:

    write(2,2)idoy,ihour
            1
Error: FORMAT label 2 at (1) not defined
```

Similar problem here: [Variable format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29558485/variable-format)

I'm not sure how to use their solution. Can someone post a general format for this kind of problem?

Comment: In what way were they "really unhappy"?  Was there an error message?  [Note that the code isn't standard Fortran.]

Comment: what does "both f77 and f95 seemed really unhappy" mean? what are the error you are getting?

Comment: Added the compiler outputs for f95 and f77. Sorry about that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29558485/variable-format)

Comment: Hmm... very close, but I'm not sure how to implement their answer.

Comment: Essentially, you create a character variable which contains the format, and you modify that format with the count before it is used.  That said, in this case, I'd just be tempted to prepend to the output list a number of blanks (adding a character field to the format) and having an unchanging format.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible approaches, and I will present three patterns below.

---

[**1st approach**] One reads two columns at a time, as suggested in the Question. Given a sample input with 4 days and 3 months per year and each time written in `'(I5)'` format,

```
   Jan       Feb    June
 rise set  rise set  rise set
 0643 1754 0433 1305 1256 0219
 1057 2230 1038 9999 1502 0151
 0912 9999           1559 0103
 1147 0149
```

we can read them as

```
integer, parameter :: Nday = 4, Nmon = 3   !! for actual data, Nday = 31 and Nmon = 12
integer, dimension( Nday, Nmon ) :: rise, set
integer :: d, m
character(200) :: lineskip

open( 10, file="time_blank.dat", status="old" )

do m = 1, Nmon
    rewind( 10 )
    read( 10, * ); read( 10, * )  !! skip the two header lines

    do d = 1, Nday
        read( 10, "(a, 2i5)" ) &
                lineskip( 1 : 10 * (m-1) ), rise( d, m ), set( d, m )
    enddo
enddo
close( 10 )
```

Here, we used `lineskip` (a dummy character string) to skip already processed data. Note that `rise` and `set` for empty fields are set to `0`, which may not be desirable depending on cases.

---

[**2nd approach**] One reads each line into a character string and then parse it to obtain integer data. For example,

```
integer :: offset
character(1000) :: line
character(5) :: str1, str2

rise(:,:) = -1 ; set(:,:) = -1   !! first, initialize all data with dummy values
...
do d = 1, Nday
    read( 10, "(a)" ) line

    do m = 1, Nmon
        offset = 10 * (m-1)
        str1 = line( offset + 1 : offset + 5  )
        str2 = line( offset + 6 : offset + 10 )
        if ( str1 /= "" ) read( str1, * ) rise( d, m )
        if ( str2 /= "" ) read( str2, * ) set ( d, m )
    enddo
enddo
```

where each row is read into `line`, divided into fields, and then integer values (if any) are extracted. Here `rise` and `set` for empty data are set to a user-defined dummy value (here, `-1`). A similar method can be used to improve the 1st approach as well.

---

[**3rd approach**] It is sometimes more convenient to have a free-format input file. To achieve this, let us fill the empty data with dummy values, e.g. -1:

```
Jan           Feb         June
rise  set     rise  set      rise set
0643  1754    0433  1305   1256 0219
1057  2230    1038  9999    1502 0151
0912  9999    -1    -1     1559 0103
1147  0149    -1    -1        -1   -1   <--- free format
```

Then we can read all the data at once as

```
open( 10, file="time_filled.dat", status="old" )
read( 10, * )   !! skip the header
read( 10, * )
read( 10, * ) ( ( rise( d, m ), set( d, m ), m=1,Nmon ), d=1,Nday )
close( 10 )
```

IMO this is the simplest and most flexible way as long as we can modify the input file.

---

[**Serializing data**] One can serialize `rise` and `set` as a function of DOY as

```
idoy = 0
do m = 1, Nmon
do d = 1, Nday
    if ( rise( d, m ) >= 0 ) then    !! assuming the dummy value = -1
        idoy = idoy + 1
        print *, idoy, rise( d, m ), set( d, m )
    endif
enddo
enddo
```

or using the `pack` function:

```
integer, allocatable :: rise_doy(:), set_doy(:)

rise_doy = pack( rise, rise >= 0 )  !! assuming the dummy value = -1
set_doy  = pack( set,  set  >= 0 )
```

(note that for Intel fortran, we need `-assume realloc_lhs` option).

Comment: I'm not very sure whether "rise" and "set" for blank fields (in the first approach) are always set to 0 by any compilers... (though gfortran and ifort seem to do so). I tried attaching iostat, but this did not work for blank fields.

Comment: For numeric input, a field consisting entirely of blanks is considered to be zero, according to the Fortran standard.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this behavior... I took a note and added one more approach :)

Comment: What happens when the thing rises or sets at midnight?  I'd be reading into a character variable and then testing that before deciding whether the field is null/empty/zero.