# Fortran variable formatting with FORMAT statement without angle brackets?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

In converting some FORTRAN code to be compatible with the GNU Fortran compiler, I need to get rid of some of the variable formatting angle brackets (<>) and replace them with equivalent GNU accepted formatting.

The problem is, I'd like to do this while still using the FORMAT statement. The reason for this is that the format statements are very complex, multi-line statements with strings and so forth, so to determine the size of the string buffer necessary for a very large code with multiple instances of variable formatting is undesirable.

That is, I could replace

```
      write(10,100)blah,blah...,blah
  100 format(... <ii>i10, 'this and that ', 
      .../
      ...)
```

with

```
      vfmt=''
      write(vfmt,'(a,...,a)')'(',...,ii,'i10','this and that ',...,')'
      write(10,vfmt)blah,blah...,blah
```

where `vfmt` is some very long string buffer, but I'd rather do this only as a last resort.

Is it possible to make the FORMAT statement *partially* variable? Something like

```
      vfmt=''
      write(vfmt,'(i0)')ii
      write(10,100)blah,blah...,blah
  100 format(..., vfmt//'i10',...)
```

I know from attempting this that this specific approach does not work.

Thanks.

Comment: In general, I'd still recommend the use of a character literal as the format.  Even with a horribly long set of edit descriptors: you can have the base format with placeholders in known locations and do substring assignment as required (so avoiding the massive write for the format).  Similarly to [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29558989).

Comment: Thanks. I changed the statement regarding `fmt=` specifier.

Comment: How about making a format function that can be used as write( 10, vfmt( 100, ii ) ) blah, blah, ... (though probably a bit slower)?

Comment: worth a note in simple cases where your variable number represents writing the entire io list you can now just use a `*`.  Otherwise you need to do the string approach.  No need to know the exact string length, just declare a string buffer length 1000 or so and use it for every format.